# C# WPF Draw a sequence of point at the border of my canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, draw, point

The set of points can be quite large and it indicates the coordinates (kind of a photoshop ruler).
It doesn't have to be too time-consuming and can be updated in case of zoom/pan.
thanx

Comment: Should the ruler scale or would a repeated bitmap suffice?

Comment: No sorry it has to be dinamic and adjust to different choices of the user. In addition I might have to add some numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a sequence of points as a rectangle using a `Rectangle` control with a `StrokeDashArray`:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Stroke="#FF000000" Height="1" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="4 4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
    <Canvas Margin="4"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That is a very brilliant solution I had not thought about !!! But I'd still like to stick to a more... conventional procedure. What about adding a collection of rectangles or ellipses? This is what I had in my mind but not sure about how to do it properly.

Comment: And as I said before I might have to add some numbers too.